# Transforming <br> and &nbsp; from xml to html is not rendering properly

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml contains data with < br> and &nbsp. When I am converting this particular data to html, **&nbsp** is not getting replaced with '**space**' and  < br> to be replaced with emty string.

**XSL code**

```
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Results"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

**XML data**

```
 <Results><![CDATA[comment asndjbaksjndkasjnhd aksjdnaksjndkas 
askdjnaskjdn    asdknaskdjn asdlknasdkljnas asldknaslkd asldkna
asdasdasdasdas<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;asddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd]]>
</Results>
```

I have searched over internet and got some suggestion to add the below in my xsl to get rid of this problem.

```
<xsl:value-of select="Results" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
```

But still its not resolving my problem. Anyone please help me?

Comment: That's because it's all inside a CDATA section. It's just character data; not markup. What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 1.0. Actually I am serializing the object to get this xml, if I am not adding this within CDATA then tags are getting serialized as &gt and &lt :(